# From PHP, test if Apache variable is defined (same as IfDefine in .htaccess)

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, variables, environment-variables

How to test from PHP whether an Apache variable is defined? In `.htaccess` this is tested with IfDefine.

When starting Apache, I define a variable: in Windows with

```
httpd.exe -D "MYVARIABLE" -w -n "Apache2.2" -k start
```

and in Ubuntu adding to `/etc/apache2/envvars`:

```
export APACHE_ARGUMENTS='-D MYVARIABLE'
```

Now I can use it in `.htaccess` as

```
<IfDefine MYVARIABLE>
    do stuff
</IfDefine>
```

and it works.

How can I test for it from PHP? I tried

```
if (getenv ('MYVARIABLE')) do stuff;
if (apache_getenv ('MYVARIABLE')) do stuff;
```

but it always returns `FALSE`.

```
phpinfo ();
```

prints a lot of things but there is no string `MYVARIABLE` in its output.

Comment: A directive name definition (`-D`) doesn't become environment variable implicitly. Use `/etc/apache2/envvars` or `SetEnv` for such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to mario's comment, I think the answer is:

- On Windows, probably no way when the variable is set as a command line argument, such as

  ```
  httpd.exe -D "MYVARIABLE" -w -n "Apache2.2" -k start
  ```
- On Linux/Ubuntu, if it is set in `/etc/apache2/envvars` as

  ```
  export APACHE_ARGUMENTS='-D MYVARIABLE'
  ```

  then from PHP

  ```
  $x = getenv ('APACHE_ARGUMENTS')
  ```

  gives `-D MYVARIABLE`, from which you can use `strstr ($x, 'MYVARIABLE')` or so to find the variable.